# JavaScript вместо Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добые люди подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать. Есть textarea в которой код должен подсвечиватся, для этого на jquery он заменяется на тег pre. в этом коде с jquery все как надо работает но как сделать то же самое на чистом JS. Textarea может быть несколько.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Test</title>

  <style>
    li.L0,
    li.L1,
    li.L2,
    li.L3,
    li.L5,
    li.L6,
    li.L7,
    li.L8 {
      list-style-type: decimal !important;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/google/code-prettify@master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <pre class="prettyprint linenums">
    <textarea>&lt;div&gt;
    &lt;h1 class="test"&gt;Example HTML&lt;/h1&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;</textarea>
</pre>


  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('pre.prettyprint textarea').each(function(i, obj) {
        var src = $(obj).val();
        $(obj).parent().text(src);
      });
      prettyPrint();
    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [You might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Comment: @Simon Спасибо помогло). 

`window.onload = function() {
 document.querySelectorAll('pre.prettyprint textarea').forEach((obj, i) => {
   let src = obj.value;
   obj.parentNode.textContent = src;
 });
 prettyPrint();
}`